# cant return li id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling in data through ajax to populate a facebook-like wall type application  (or a twitter wall).

But I'm getting undefined when i try to access the first li- if anyone can spot my obvious mistake it would be appreciated

```
var get_venues = function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<?=base_url()?>wall/start_to_grab/',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                var sel = $("#wall");
                sel.empty();    

                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

                  sel.append('<li id="'+data[i].post_id +'"> ' + data[i].title + '</li>');

                }


            }
        });
        //start_poll($('ul#wall li:first').attr('id'));
        alert($("ul#wall li:first").attr("id")); // returns undefined
    };
```

The code returns undefined even when i can see the element on the page.

Comment: Use synchronous AJAX request....
set `async : false,`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the way AJAX works (asynchronously, as the name suggests). The `alert` is executed before the AJAX request has returned a response, so no `li` elements have been appended.

Move the `alert` inside the AJAX success event handler. Alternatively, you could make the AJAX request synchronous, but that's almost always not what you want.

Comment: Also, use `$('<li />', {id: data[i].post_id, html: data[i].title})` to create a li element using jQuery (:

Comment: my mistake on thinking it would execute proceduraly after the ajax call, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) This is a very common mistake to make. There is a question like yours at least every day on here.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is trying to access the results of an asynchronous request before the asynchronous request has completed. Simply put, when you attempt to alert your ID, the async request hasn't yet completed and therefore hasn't appended the li. The solution is to call a function within the async request that alerts your ID:

```
var get_venues = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<?=base_url()?>wall/start_to_grab/',
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            var sel = $("#wall");
            sel.empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                sel.append('<li id="' + data[i].post_id + '"> ' + data[i].title + '</li>');
                // Request complete, call handler to alert ID
                HandleResponse()
            }
        }
    });
};

function HandleResponse() {
    alert($("ul#wall li:first").attr("id")); // returns undefined
}​
```